# Closing authentication popup selenium

Tags: python, selenium, popup

Is there possibility to close popup authentication window via **selenium**

I wrote something like thath:

```
def Alert():
    alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
    alert.dismiss()
```

I do not need to authenticate this session. Simple closure of window is enought.

Authentication is granted by domain user im logged into :)

@Edit i do not need to log in i just need to close the window

Comment: you mean http authentication?

Comment: i need to close window not login so it does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only close window from multiple try like this

```
# Show all windows
print(driver.window_handles)

# Switch last open window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[len(driver.window_handles) - 1])

# Close last open window
driver.close()
```